# ARKit Convert 3d object position to UIView coordinates

Tags: ios, arkit

I have created measure demo which allow to put multiple points and show distance between them. which works fine

I want to show preview that what so far has been drawn in real world to the UIView using `UIBezierPath` .  Just like http://armeasure.com/

I have tried many things to achieve this but I couldn't find any right way to do it.

```
if self.linkList.count == 1 {
    bezierPath.removeAllPoints()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10,y: 10))
} else {
    guard self.linkList.count > 1 ,let object2 = self.linkList.lastNode, let object1 = self.linkList.lastNode?.previous else {return}


    let value = self.getMeasurementXandYBetween(vector1: object1.node.mainNode.position, and: object2.node.mainNode.position)
    print(value)
    let x = Double((object1.node.mainNode.position.x + value ) * 377.9527559055 )
    let y = Double((object1.node.mainNode.position.y + value) * 377.9527559055)
    let pointCoordinates = CGPoint(x: x , y: y)
    print("x : Y ",x,y)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: pointCoordinates)

}
shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.5
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)


self.viewToDraw.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
func getMeasurementXandYBetween(vector1:SCNVector3, and vector2:SCNVector3) -> Float {
    return sqrtf((vector1.x - vector2.x) * (vector1.x - vector2.x) +  (vector1.y - vector2.y) * (vector1.y - vector2.y))
}
```

The logic I used (which is not working is) Location of previous node + distance I got from `getMeasurementXandYBetween`  multiply by 377.

Please suggest a hint or any other solution

[image]

Comment: Why use a `UIBezierPath`? That would mean you need to recalculate everything with every frame because all coordinates change?

Comment: I need to draw into uiview see the screen shot attachment to lower left corner
That red line should be same as green lines that what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of any point in screen-space by using the [`projectPoint()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint) on your `SCNSceneRenderer`. 
This will give you a vector with 3 elements, build your `CGPoint` using the first two and build your shape from those points.

Comment: Thank you able to get it half working  but still there is fight with math

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya feel free to ask a new question or update the old one.

Comment: Any updates with this? I'm also facing this issue, I'm converting the 3D coordinates to 2D by using projectPoint(_:orientation:viewportSize:). But the shape is not correct while I draw it in a UIView.

Comment: @ak_ninan Best to ask a new question with your goal, your current code and maybe an example what isn't working.